# When does Photoshop generate feature 'do the generate'?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, automation, generate-image-assets

I've got an action that alters sone layers slightly on a large batch of psd files.

I basically open psd run action, close the psd file and move on to the next.

While review thing files later I saw that some of the files that were generated had been generated before the action had altered it.

Is there specific instances when generate runs or can be forced to run? So I can control 'when' it generates a layer within an action that contains several adjustments?

Comment: You mean the `File > Generate > Image assets`? That spits out the assets whenever the psd file is saved.

Comment: Yes. How do I control or 'force' it to generate the current state while working through a multiple step process? is "save file" the command that forces generate to execute?

Comment: Well it's kinda hard to say without knowing the things you are doing but basically save the document once after all the edits are done... That should do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If You Talking About `File-Generate-Image assets` then it's quite simple;
Basically When This Option is enabled-

It Loops Through All layers and searches for suffixes like .png .jpg .gif .svg and so on and once it finds such layer name; it automatically saves that layer or group with that name; **Hard To Understand? here is example:**

Assume you have a group of 3 Layers named Circle; Square and Image; and your group name is MyShapes;
If You Rename Group to MyShapes.jpg And When you save the file; you will get A new folder with name **[yourPSDname]-assets** and under that folder, you will find a jpg created. It's kinda handy when you make web designs and app designs.

**Pros** =  Saves A Lot Of Time With Many supported file types. svg also supported but useless since it will not convert your layer to vector.

**Cons** = Each saved Layers will be trimmed automatically So Don't use this if you want some free margin left in your assets;
**[Refer Here For More Information](https://helpx.adobe.com/in/photoshop/using/generate-assets-layers.html)**